# Javascript window.open from iFrame

Tags: javascript, iframe, window.open

I have this JavaScript + PHP utility to download files from server.
The problem is that this page needs to be embedded into another page through iFrame. This parent page doesn't have the 'allow-downloads' property set for the iFrame and I don't have a control over it, so I cannot change that. The result is that the download doesn't work in Chrome. So, in order to go around this, I thought that I would call the download link in a popup window with the help of JavaScript's window.open.

I have one XMLHttpRequest to receive list of files in requested directory on the server.
In the response, I receive list of files in the directory. I'm displaying them in a table:
The important thing is that I'm also creating download button for each file. I'm setting bunch of attributes for the button (to identify the file to which the button belongs to):

```
if (request.status == 200) {
                responseData = JSON.parse(request.response);
                var files = responseData.output;
                for (var i = 0; i < Object.keys(files).length; i++) {
                    //Some code to generate rows/cells in a table...
                    var btn = document.createElement('button');
                    btn.innerText = 'Download';
                    btn.setAttribute('dir',dir);
                    btn.setAttribute('file',files[i]['name']);
                    btn.setAttribute('onClick','downloadFile(this)')  
                }
```

One of the attributes is "onClick" attribute that calls downloadFile function with parameter that references to the button element. The downloadFile function currently looks like this:

```
function downloadFile(element) {
    var dir_name = element.getAttribute('dir');
    var file_name = element.getAttribute('file');
    var download_link = 'download.php?action=download&dir=' + dir_name +'&file=' + file_name;
    window.open(download_link);
}
```

This works like a charm when I visit the page directly. But when I embed it inside the iFrame and click on the button, the new tab is opened, the URL is even correctly filled into the address bar, but nothing happens. I need to hit refresh or hit enter in the address box to confirm the address. Then the file is downloaded.
I was trying couple of things, for example instead of `window.open(download_link);` line to use:

```
var popup_window = window.open();
popup_window.location = download_link;
popup_window.reload();
```

and so on but it does not help - with this, blank tab is opened and nothing is downloaded.

I'll appreciate any help/suggestion. Or if there's another way how to go around the iFrame download restriction, I'm all in!

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: `open('yourPage.php', 'Window Title')`. Just do your download with PHP. Just make `yourPage.php` like Example #1 in [readfile](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php#example-2973). And... yes, you can always leave `window.` off. It's implicit.

Comment: Thank you for your response, @StackSlave . That's actually how I'm already handling downloads on the PHP side, I just need to pass some arguments to identify directory/file, that's why I'm passing a bit more arguments in the "download_link". But as I already said, it is on working when I use it inside an iframe - it will open the new tab with correct link in the address bar, but I need to confirm it/refresh the page for the download to initiate. When used outside the iframe, it works fine.